# Create a datetime in Rails using month, day, and year

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have `params[:month,:day,:year]` and I need to convert them into a `DateTime` that I can place in a hidden input.

What's the best way to do this in Rails 3?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can do

```
DateTime.new(params[:year], params[:month], params[:day])
```

Comment: Indeed. This worked without the require statement. Thank you!

Comment: I think they all must be converted to integer! Because DateTime.new is only working with integers, not strings.

params[:year].to_i etc.

Answer (score 12):

Use [`DateTime.civil`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/DateTime.html#M000482):

```
require 'date'
date = DateTime.civil( *params.values_at( :year, :month, :day ) )
```

Comment: Sorry. I'm a complete noob. Would I put that require at the top of my controller or in the method?

Comment: At the top of your controller file, @bjork24